# How to pass environment variables into Haskell programs run via stack?

Tags: haskell, environment-variables, haskell-stack, nixos

I just noticed that Haskell programs run via `stack` do not receive environment variables from the calling environment. Here's a sample program:

```
-- testenv.hs
import System.Environment
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< getEnv "FOOBAR"
```

If I run it without stack, like this, it works:

```
% FOOBAR=123 runhaskell testenv.hs
"123"
```

But using stack:

```
% FOOBAR=123 stack runhaskell testenv.hs
testenv.hs: FOOBAR: getEnv: does not exist (no environment variable)
```

Same goes for when it is compiled: `FOOBAR=123 stack exec testenv` fails while `FOOBAR=123 .stack-work/install/BLAHBLAH/testenv` works.

**Is there a way to force stack to pass-through certain environment variables?**

The real problem I'm having is with `yesod devel`, there are some settings I want to override with environment variables, but `yesod devel` uses stack to run the program so they don't go through.

This is stack 1.6.5 on NixOS 18.03.132262.0a73111bc29.

Comment: For stack 1.6.5 I cannot reproduce it with your example. Could it be some other, special environment variable?

Comment: Yeah I can't reproduce your issue either but the way to do it is compile it and run it with `FOOBAR=123 stack exec mybin`.

`stack exec` seems to be what you want.

Comment: Actually I meant `stack exec` when I said `stack run` – I'll edit the question – but it's the same behavior whether it's `stack runhaskell` / `stack runghc` / `stack exec`. This is stack-1.6.5 but on NixOS, so maybe a bug with packaging?

Comment: This does have something to do with NixOS. I had `nix: enable: true` in my global `config.yaml`. After I turned this off, environment variables pass through as they should. I thought nix support in stack only meant that it would install non-Haskell dependencies using nix; but it seems like it might be running stack in a nix-shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like this is the [relevant section of the stack manual](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#the-nix-shell), which I missed:

> “By default, stack will run the build in a pure Nix build environment
>   (or shell), which means two important things: (1) basically no
>   environment variable will be forwarded from your user session to the
>   nix-shell [...]”

So this advice worked:

> “To override this behaviour, add pure: false to your stack.yaml or
>   pass the --no-nix-pure option to the command line.”

```
% FOOBAR=123 stack --no-nix-pure runhaskell testenv.hs
"123"
```